# Return logs in flask to frontend and display dynamically

Tags: python, flask, logging, request, streamlit

I am trying to push the logs generated by another python script called in my flask api to the front end (streamlit) in real time. This is what i have done so far but failed.

**flask.py**

```
@api.route('/predict', methods = ['POST']) 
def make_predictions():
    url = request.get_json(force=True)

    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('--weights', nargs='+', type=str, help='model path(s)') 
    opt = parser.parse_args(f"--weights best.pt".split())

    def inner():
        import logging
        logger = logging.getLogger('yolov5')
        handler = logging.FileHandler('predict.log')
        logger.addHandler(handler)

        predict.main(opt) <---the main prediction python script which output the logs
   
        with open('predict.log') as f:
            while True:
                yield f.read()
                sleep(1)
        
    return api.response_class(inner(), mimetype='text/plain')
```

The logs from `predict.main` are shown properly in the terminal.

**streamlit.py**

```
with st.form(key='my_form'):
    url = st.text_input("Image / Video URL", placeholder="Please enter image url")
    submit = st.form_submit_button(label='Submit')

if submit:
    response = requests.post('http://localhost:8080/predict', json=json.dumps(url), stream=True)
    for chunk in response.iter_content(1024):
        print(chunk)
```

However, the logs in streamlit are only printed out as a whole chunk. What i need is to be able to output the logs from `flask.py` at almost the same time in `streamlit.py`

Thanks!